# mysql select user only if they are in the top 12 newest records

Tags: mysql

I want to run a check to see if the username is in the top 12 most recent registered users. I only want mysql to return a result if they are in the 12 most recent. I want to sort it by id.

I've tried:

```
  Select * FROM users WHERE uname ='$uname' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 12
```

When I run this query, it shows the username weather they are in the top 12 most recent or not. Any ideas?

I didn't put a timestamp or date on the register form, so it needs to be sorted by id.

Thanks!

Comment: Add an `ORDER BY` whatever name the timstemp column has.

Comment: You should look for "recent registered users" and then for uname in this...

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want just the 12 top most users or all users and a marker along with them, telling if the user is in the top 12 or not?

Answer (score 1):

If you want check if the uname is in the last 12  (assuming that you have an auto_increment  id ) you could select the most recent in subquery and join for what you are looking

```
  select uname  from users WHERE uname ='$uname' 
  INNER JOIN (
    Select uname  FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 12 
  ) t on tuname = users.uname
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look for "recent registered users" and then for uname in this...

Something like this where dateRegistered is you column name where you have the registered date data...

```
select * FROM users 
 WHERE uname in (select uname FROM users ORDER BY dateRegistered DESC LIMIT 12)
```

Comment: This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'